# Getting directed to 404 page in Spring Boot backend

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I am working on Spring Boot application. I have my `jsp` frontend and my java backend. When I up the project in tomcat server I can see the frontend get upped. But when I try to direct the url to check the backend performance I am getting directed to 404.

**Example `http://localhost:8090/orders`**

`@RequestMapping` paths were defined in the correct way.I am using workbench in my case.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/csse_ass
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

pom.xml (I have so many dependencies, I add the essential one here)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

controller

```
private OrderService orderService;

@RequestMapping("/orders")
public List<Order> getAllOrders(){
    return orderService.getAllOrders();
}
```

service

```
@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

public List<Order> getAllOrders(){
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Order order : orderRepository.findAll()) {
        orders.add(order);
    }
    return orders;
}
```

repository

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order,String> {}
```

As well as I have my `order.java` class.I hope it doesn't matter in this problem.

I get no errors in my terminal except the tomcat errors which is common.

**Question**
Why I am getting directed to 404 page as I mentioned in the very top of the question?
Somebody fix this issue for me, cuz I couldn't figure out the problem.

Comment: Downvotes, it's fine. Explain me why?

Comment: Might you be forgetting `@Controller` on top of your controller so that Spring doesn't actually initiate an instance of it?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Currently I have the `@RestController` annotation in my code.

Comment: I hardly think that it would have something to do with `@RestController` vs `@Controller`, but I would definitely try with `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody @RequestMapping(value = "/orders", method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral It didn't help. Is this 404 is directed because of the wrong db connection?  Because I have no option to test the db connection.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with database connection, it may have something to do with `List<Order>` being empty? Could you manually populate a list of `<Order>` and try to return it from the method?

Comment: Hm, maybe your `@RestController` is not initiated because it is not scanned. Can you add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.to.your.controller")`?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I am working on it sir

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I tried the both. Added a harcorded list, and also this.`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.to.your.controller")` But still I am getting the 404 page

Comment: I need to see more of your code, at least your controller. Could you update the question/post it to GitHub etc?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral  I added the whole source code here. Front-end is working fine. Please check it out . I have only 2 more days for this. https://github.com/ramesh-inc/new

Comment: Where is your `@SpringBootApplication`(s)?

Comment: Do you mean the dependency?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral You mean the initializer class? I have a working project which doesn't have the initializer. So I removed the class.

Comment: I mean the application itself.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Sorry sir, I have no idea about what you are talking. Can you give me a explanation and a working answer.

Comment: I am referring to your main method.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@ResponseBody
public List<Order> getAllOrders(){
    return orderService.getAllOrders();
}
```

use @Controller annotation also..

Comment: It didn't help sir.